# How do you get to you APP.CONFIG

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I am working in VB.NET and I am familiar with working in the vb[design] view as well as regular vb.  I am looking to view/edit my APP.CONFIG file how do I access this file?  I am using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it a couple of ways, first by adding it via the new item dialog as you would a new class file, etc... OR by double clicking on the My Project Icon and going to your settings tab and adding settings.  This will aso create the app.config.

Answer (score 2):

The file should be in your project root directory. You can open it by double clicking it in the solution explorer. If the file is not there, you will need to add it using the  add new item dialog (from the Project menu), and choosing "Application configuration file"